# In Vue, anyway to reference to the element when binding attributes in template?

Tags: vuejs2

In template scope, are there variable referencing the element itself like a $this or $el?

Instead of,

```
<template>
    <div @click="$emit('xxx')" :class="{active:mode=='xxx'}" something_for_xxx></div>
    <div @click="$emit('yyy')" :class="{active:mode=='yyy'}" something_for_yyy></div>
    <div @click="$emit('zzz')" :class="{active:mode=='zzz'}" something_for_zzz></div>
</template>
```

Can we write something like the following, to avoid forgetting to change one of the mode name?

```
<template>
    <div mode="xxx" @click="$emit($this.mode)" :class="{active:mode==$this.mode}" something_for_xxx></div>
    <div mode="yyy" @click="$emit($this.mode)" :class="{active:mode==$this.mode}" something_for_yyy></div>
    <div mode="zzz" @click="$emit($this.mode)" :class="{active:mode==$this.mode}" something_for_zzz></div>
</template>
```

**Workaround:**

```
<template>
    <div v-for"mode_ in ["xxx"] @click="$emit(mode_)" :class="{active:mode==mode_}" something_for_xxx></div>
    <div v-for"mode_ in ["yyy"] @click="$emit(mode_)" :class="{active:mode==mode_}" something_for_yyy></div>
    <div v-for"mode_ in ["zzz"] @click="$emit(mode_)" :class="{active:mode==mode_}" something_for_zzz></div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the typical situation where you should build your elements in a [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) loop:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '#my-component',
  props: {
    mode: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      modes: ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'],
    };
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    mode: 'xxx',
  },
  methods: {
    log(event) {
      this.mode = event;
      console.log(event);
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component
      :mode='mode'
      @click="log($event)"
  ></my-component>
</div>

<template id="my-component">
  <div>
    <div
        v-for="currentMode of modes"
        @click="$emit('click', currentMode)"
        :class="{active:mode==currentMode}"
        class="pointer"
    >{{currentMode}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event handlers, you can always access `$event.target` to access the element (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) but for inline binding (like `:class`) you cannot because the element has not been rendered yet.

I suggest you change how you cycle through each *value*

```
<div v-for="elMode in ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']"
     @click="$emit('click', elMode)" :class="{active:mode==elMode}"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, but when things are still in drafting phrase, writing loops seems not very good. But I realize that you can use v-for="x in ['a']" to define local variable =D.

Comment: @somebody4 sorry, I'm not sure what your comment means

Comment: For example, elements for xxx yyy zzz may not be exactly the same. They may just share some and only some common properties/logic.